Pressure-treated wood truly necessary for basement furring strips?
Best practice described everywhere is to use pressure-treated wood when the wood will be in contact with concrete. In general, that makes great sense, especially when framing to finish a basement with drywall.
But when it's a handful of furring strips for holding up a workshop french cleat system, will PT wood truly be necessary? I'm interested in simply using some wood I have on hand. Some relevant details:

Basement is below-grade
Furring will not extend down to the floor
No drywall; the furring will be open to the air in a well-ventilated room


I believe it is more of the wood surface touching the cement surface holding a bit of moisture, than being closed or open space.  The open space will slow down, but might not negate everything.

You can put strips of sill seal or similar material between the concrete and the wood so it's NOT in direct contact.

@Ecnerwal I'm going to take your recommendation to use sill seal under most of the strips. For science, I'm going to attach a couple of the most visible strips directly to the concrete. Perhaps there will be a difference in a couple years, and we'll have a more direct answer
